# Error Importing Requests Module in Flask Backend

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am currently trying to integrate a flask backend to my react web-app. In my flask subdirectory, I have installed requests module as shown below but I keep running into an unresolved import error although I have installed the module. I have tried to follow different troubleshooting suggestions online but none seem to work. Would really appreciate if someone can help me out.[image: My terminal shows that the requests module has been installed as shown in the following image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like that the terminal and the IDE use two different environments.

You should either create a virtual env with PyCharm directly, or choose the existing one.

Please read the PyCharm documentation:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

There, either choose "New environment" or "Existing environment".

Comment: Thanks for your answer:) Would exiting the virtual environment on terminal and installing the module solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, please exit the terminal completely. Then either create or choose a virtual environment via PyCharm, install `requests` and then open the terminal again. Hope this works out for you! Please have a look at the link above, the PyCharm documentation.